# Расчёт dp экрана

Tags: android

Есть ли программный способ рассчитать количество dp экрана по вертикали и горизонтали? Ну, чтоб, допустим, в логи вывести: "dp: 160".

Comment: https://ciox.ru/calculator-ppi-dpi это имеете ввиду?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
DisplayMetrics displayMetrics = context.getResources().getDisplayMetrics();    
float dpHeight = displayMetrics.heightPixels / displayMetrics.density;
float dpWidth = displayMetrics.widthPixels / displayMetrics.density;
```

Comment: а что за `context`?

Comment: Контекст. Если вам нужно получать высоту и ширину экрана в активности, то можете опустить его, тоесть просто `getResources()...`, а если где-нибудь в другом месте то используйте `getApplicationContext()`.